# Summing values in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

Sorry, I did not state my question clearly. I have a variable x that I keep iterating over and I want to include x and its corresponding sub- dictionary in a dictionary.

For example, x represents bus station number. Bus station number 6 might have a distance of value1 from the bus starting station and a distance of variable2 from the bus' last station.

Since I don't know what bus station I am in at any given time, I don't have all the info in a dictionary.

I want to start with an empty dictionary and update the different station distance information iteratively.

```
d1={}

d1 = {1: {'a': variable1, 'b': variable2}, 2: {'a': variable3, 'b': variable4}}
```

I want to insert a key:value pair of 'c': 'value' to d1 as shown below by adding the values in the sub dict (the sum of the values of 'a' and 'b').

```
d1= {1: {'a': 11, 'b': 22, 'c': 'value'}, 2: {'a': 456, 'b': 789, 'c': 'value'}}
```

I want the value for each 'c' of the bus station to be

```
value = variable1 + variable2
value = variable3 + variable4
```

I hope I have clarified my question a little better now. It's my very first question on stackoverflow and I don't think I worded my question clearly. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: It looks like you almost have it. What's the trouble?

Comment: Those dictionaries are illegible, please update them.

Comment: Please see my updated question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Building onto what you have nearly got..

```
d1[1]['c'] = d1[1]['a'] + d1[1]['b']
d1[2]['c'] = d1[2]['a'] + d1[2]['b']
```

This is not the pythonic way of doing things(Ryan Stein's answer is), the other answers are. But this shows another way to access values in dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for Python3:

```
d1= {1: {'a': 14, 'b': 16}, 2: {'a':15,  'b': 15}}
new_data = {a:{**{c:d for c, d in b.items()}, **{'c':sum(b.values())}} for a, b in d1.items()}
```

Output:

```
{1: {'a': 14, 'b': 16, 'c': 30}, 2: {'a': 15, 'b': 15, 'c': 30}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you want the keys `'a'` and `'b'` of each dictionary entry summed into the key of `'c'`, a `for` loop will suffice in terms of completeness and readability.

```
d1 = {1: {'a': 11, 'b': 22}, 2: {'a': 456, 'b': 789}}

for item in d1.values():
    item['c'] = item['a'] + item['b']


print(d1)
```

`{1: {'a': 11, 'b': 22, 'c': 33}, 2: {'a': 456, 'b': 789, 'c': 1245}}`

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the `dict`. Add the new key in inner `dict` objects.

```
for key in d1:
    d1.get(key)['c'] = sum(d1.get(key).values())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d1= {1: {'a': 11, 'b': 22, 'c': 'value'}, 2: {'a': 456, 'b': 789, 'c': 'value'}}

# d1[1]['c']=33
# d1[2]['c']=1245

for numbers in d1:
    total = d1[numbers]["a"] + d1[numbers]["b"]
    d1[numbers]["c"] = total

print(d1[1]["c"])
print(d1[2]['c'])
```

Comment: The sum are accurate and it loops through each dictionary.

Comment: Shouldn't use `sum` as a variable name, that's already a python builtin function.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve with list comprehension & sum,

```
v1, v2, v3, v4 = 10, 5, 2, 3
d1 = {1: {'a': v1, 'b': v2}, 2: {'a': v3, 'b': v4}}

[d1[k].update({'c': sum(v.values())}) for k,v in d1.items()]

print(d1) # {1: {'a': 10, 'c': 15, 'b': 5}, 2: {'a': 2, 'c': 5, 'b': 3}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dict is known to be only two level a comprehension could be used.

```
{k: dict(zip(v.keys() + ['c'], v.values() + [sum(v.values())])) for k,v in d1.items()}
```